# How to disable One-Finger swipe for Magic Mouse on windows

Tags: windows, macos, mouse

Using Magic Mouse 2.0 on Windows 8.1 turns into disaster.

It is hard to click anything without scrolling the screen. Is it was possible to disable one finger swipe?

Is there any utility for windows that enables control over mouse settings?

Answer (score 1):

The Magic Mouse is Apple's proprietary mouse, meaning that there won't be an Apple certified way to change it within Windows.

Utilities to change Magic Mouse settings in Windows probably won't exist either for the same reason – the Magic Mouse is specifically made for Macs and OS X.